# Django quick file delete

Tags: django, django-views

I have an issue with my small project. Basically, my site will have user accounts, each of them allows images to be uploaded to the server (lets say like a gallery). Obviously I don't want all the images to appear in a single folder, so I implemented it so that each user's images will only go to their respective directory.

The problem is, while users can upload, I don't know how to make it so they can delete these files.

Table "ImageDoc" has a column "imgfile", which stores the name of the file.

view.py

```
def image_galleria(request):
    LOCATION = request.user.username + "/"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImgDocForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            origin_form = form.cleaned_data["user_file"]
            origin_name = origin_form.name
            new_name = origin_name.split('.')[0] + ".jpg"
            original_file = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+LOCATION, new_name)

            original_name = ImageDoc(user_id=user_details.id, imgfile=new_name)
            original_name.save()
```

The code works above, it saves to the user's respective directories. However...

view.py

```
@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def delete_image(request, image_id):
    imagex = ImageDoc.objects.get(id=image_id)
    LOCATION = request.user.username + "/"
    imagex.imgfile.delete(LOCATION)

    return HttpResponse("Yes! Deleted file!")
```

I tried various combos of ".delete()", which doesn't work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the file just get the `file` object and delete it... In your case it should be

```
imagex.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. It doesn't work though.This works however: 

'imagex.imgfile.delete()'

But my issue is that the delete function isn't deleting the file inside the user's directory, just the general MEDIA directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by using another method. For future reference:

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def delete_image(request, image_id):
    imagex = ImageDoc.objects.get(id=image_id)

    imgfile = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + request.user.username + "/" + imagex.imgfile.name
    os.remove(imgfile)

    imagex.imgfile.delete()
    imagex.delete()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('image_galleria'))
```

Rather rough solution, but it works I suppose. Thanks!